# My isotope (jQuery plugin) is not filtering when the identifying class is passed props in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, jquery-isotope

My isotope filtering is working perfectly when the identifying class is hard-coded in the grid elements, but it fails to function when the elements are rendered using jQuery Ajax call in ReactJS, and the identifying class are set using props passed to it by parent component.

When I hard-code the `className="block hvr-reveal CategoryA "` , then it seems to work fine, but when I pass the same through props, it doesn't.

Also it's getting displayed if I append a `<p>` tag right after the `<img>` tag and display `{this.props.category}`.

```
var Template = React.createClass({
              render: function() {
                return (
                  <div className="container text-center">
                    <div className="block hvr-reveal {this.props.category} " data-category={this.props.category} >
                        <img src={this.props.url}></img>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                );
              }
            });
```

Comment: Obviously the javascript doesn't get evaluated because it's inside quotes `"`, or inside html. Try generating the html differently.